# R Shiny change colour of data frame outline

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame in my server file as follows

```
output$table<-renderTable({
        P.Value<- c(lev.p,bart.p,turn.p,shap.p,jar.p,linm.p) 
        Test.Statistic<-c(lev.s,bart.s,turn.s,shap.s,jar.s,linm.s) 
        df<-data.frame(P.Value,Test.Statistic)
        rownames(df, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "row")
        rownames(df) <- c("Levene Test","Bartlett Test","Turning Point Test","Shapiro-Wilk Test","Jarque Bera Test","Linear Model Constant Drift Test")

        df
  })
```

and the ui as

```
column(5,tableOutput("table")
```

this produces a table as follows
[image]

However I want to turn the grey outline of the table into another colour, such as black. How do i go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: The styling of elements in a shiny application can be controlled via CSS. Look at [Style your apps with CSS](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is an example of how to style your borders in the table. Please go to [Tip: Adding borders to data tables with CSS](http://www.webteacher.ws/2010/03/29/tip-adding-borders-to-data-tables-with-css/) for further details.  Also familiarise yourself with [datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) and look into the [DT package](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/). Here I used tags to style the borders (the header in blue and the rest in black). You can google the CSS colours or examples can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp).

**Edit:** You can control border also with pixels: `border-width: 5px;` Look [here](http://w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp) for more info

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

test_table <- cbind(rep(as.character(Sys.time()),10),rep('a',10),rep('b',10),rep('b',10),rep('c',10),rep('c',10),rep('d',10),rep('d',10),rep('e',10),rep('e',10))
colnames(test_table) <- c("Time","Test","T3","T4","T5","T6","T7","T8","T9","T10")

ui =navbarPage(inverse=TRUE,title = "Coloring Table Borders",
               tabPanel("Logs",icon = icon("bell"),mainPanel(htmlOutput("logs"))),
               tags$style(type="text/css", "#logs th, td {border: medium solid #00F;text-align:center}"),
               tags$style(type="text/css", "#logs td {border: medium solid #000000;text-align:center}"))

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  my_test_table <- reactive({as.data.frame(test_table)})
  output$logs <- renderTable({my_test_table()},include.rownames=FALSE)
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: thanks! Quick question for the tags$style(type="text/css", "#logs td {border: medium solid #000000;text-align:center}") part, how do you make the outline less thick?

Comment: you can control it with pixels, e.g border-width: 5px; look here for more info http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp